# Manipulating a list of strings using the Unreal Python API

Tags: python, string, unreal-engine5

Using the Unreal Python API.
https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/PythonAPI/

In the following method I am creating a list called assetPaths.

```
    import unreal
    def listAssetPaths() :
        EAL = unreal.EditorAssetLibrary 
        assetPaths = EAL.list_assets('/Game')
    for assetPath in assetPaths: print (assetPath)
```

The problem is that each entry in the assetPaths list contains a duplicate of the object at the end of each path. ie

```
/Game/ProjectName/Textures/Utility/Texture1_01a.Texture1_01a
```

It's this last ***.Texture1_01a***  that must be removed.

I've spent a couple hours trying the split() method without success.
How can I repopulate the assetPaths list with the results I need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the below is along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
import unreal

def listAssetPaths():
    EAL = unreal.EditorAssetLibrary
    result = []
    assetPaths = EAL.list_assets('/Game')
    for assetPath in assetPaths:
       result.append(str(assetPath).split('.')[0])
    return result
print(listAssetPaths())
```

I would be curious what issues you ran into with split but I'm guessing you may have been trying to edit assetPath directly. I would avoid doing this by using a secondary list as I've done in the example above.